# JQuery with PHP, using $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I've been struggling for the entire day, I can't seem to get it right to send through a JSON object to a PHP file using the $.ajax function. I eventually got it right to send it through but now it refuses to decode.

//JQuery File

```
            var user = 
        {
            "email" : document.getElementById('email1').value,
            "password" : document.getElementById('pwd1').value,
            "fname" : document.getElementById('firstname').value,
            "lname" : document.getElementById('lastname').value,
            "gender" : Validator.getGender(),
            "dob" : document.getElementById('dob').value
        }; 
       JSON.stringify(user);

            user = {json:user};

            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "register.php",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: user,
                    success: function(result)
                    {       

                        alert("It worked :D");
                        alert(result);
                    },
                    failure: function()
                    {

                        alert('whoops');
                    }
                });
```

//PHP File

```
<?php
    $json = $_REQUEST['json'];
    $json = stripslashes($json);

    $jsonobj = json_decode($json);

    $fname = $jsonobj->fname;
    $lname = $jsonobj->lname;
    $password = $jsonobj->password;
    $email = $jsonobj->email;
    $gender = $jsonobj->gender;
    $dob = $jsonobj->dob;
    echo $gender;
```

?>

Am I doing something completely silly ? I'm just echoing the gender variable back for now but am actually going to use this to enter it into a database.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

How would it would it work if my php file looked like this:

```
    session_start();
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
if(!$db)
{
    die("DB connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

$db_select = mysql_select_db("tinyspace", $db);
if(!$db_select)
{
    die("DB connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

$json_string = $_REQUEST["json"];
$jsonobj = json_decode($_REQUEST["json"]);
$fname = $jsonobj -> fname;
$lname = $jsonobj -> lname;
$pwd = $jsonobj -> password;
$email = $jsonobj -> email;
$gender = $jsonobj -> gender;
$dob = $jsonobj -> dob;

$sql("INSERT INTO tinyspace.users (email, password, firstname, lastname, gender, dob) VALUES ('$email','$password','$fname', '$lname','$gender','$dob')");

if (!mysql_query($sql,$db))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($db);
```

Comment: Datatype parameter defines the type of data that you're expecting back and not the type you are sending to the server, just remove to let JQuery analyse the server response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `datatype =json` and trying to echo result.So it won't work it will accept only json data

you need to remove this

```
dataType: 'json',
```

or echo someting like this

```
$gender=array();
$gender['gender']=$jsonobj->gender
echo json_encode($gender);
```

You are also not creating the json

use this

```
var user = 
        {
            "email" : document.getElementById('email1').value,
            "password" : document.getElementById('pwd1').value,
            "fname" : document.getElementById('firstname').value,
            "lname" : document.getElementById('lastname').value,
            "gender" : Validator.getGender(),
            "dob" : document.getElementById('dob').value
        }; 
      var userjson= JSON.stringify(user);

            user = {json:userjson};
```

or

```
data:{'json' :userjson}
```

Comment: But in the case where for example I don't want to return anything and just want to add the data to a database, how would I let it know that it was successful ?

Comment: Yeah, just don't specify the datatype; `$.ajax()` is good enough at determining the type itself. (This is why I usually use `$.post()`, which uses the right defaults for 99% of cases).

Comment: @Crossman you can use `dataType: 'html'`  or you can use proper encoding serverside.

Comment: You also shouldn't need the `JSON.stringify(user);` or `user = {json:user};`. IIRC $.ajax() can handle objects as parameter values just fine.